# Including typedefs from immutable v4.0.0-rc2 in flow

Tags: flowtype, immutable.js, flow-typed

I'm using the Immutable library (v4.0.0-rc2) and am trying to setup flow to use the typedefs included with the library.  The typedefs are located at `immutable/dist/immutable.js.flow`, which I've duplicated under my project's `./flow-typed/npm` directory.

The problem that I have is that flow works with every other module *but* Immutable and I keep getting an error whenever I attempt to include the module: `required module not found`.

Having inspected the contents of `immutable.js.flow`, there is no `declare module` block anywhere to be found, which I believe to be the cause of the error.  There are a bunch of `export` statements at the end of the file though.

How can I include the typedefs so the thing just works? IOW, what can I do that doesn't involve providing the typedefs under a manually-created `declare module` block?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special. You shouldn't even need to copy the definitions into your `flow-typed/npm` directory. You're not ignoring `node_modules` in your `.flowconfig`, are you?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using latest version of immutablejs library, all you need to do is install flow-typed library

Then just run

```
yarn flow-typed install
```

This should install all flow-typed dependencies based on your project's `package.json` and it will also create module declarations for any packages which don't have flow types yet.

And you don't need to copy any immutable flow definitions from `node_modules` to `flow-typed/npm` directory, because `flow-typed` will resolve automatically the flow types either from `node_modules` or from flow-typed/npm directory.